# Entity Framework Core: Does the foreign key default to nullable for a many to one relationship?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am relatively new with EF Core. I thought EF Core would default foreign keys to non-nullable for a many to one relationship. We have defined the relationship like this (using the standard example):

```
public class Blog
{
  public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
  // No explicit reference back to Blog. EF creates a shadow property.
}
```

The foreign key on `Post` in the database automatically seems to become nullable.

1. Is this the default behvior of EF Core? I don't know why I thought it wasn't, to be honset. Maybe it's off to stop people accidentally cascade deleting things.
2. I can't seem to find the documentation for this. Can someone point me in the right direction? I've looked here: [Shadow and Indexer Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties), [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships), and a few other places.